# How to create such a layout?

Tags: html, css, layout

How do I create one layout in HTML + CSS?

The problem that I have is that I did not realize how to properly split screen.
Can you give a brief example please `jsfiddle`

[image]

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**

I put this example that please if you know to edit any variant of solving the problem. Very important ... the two bottom divs should always be square

https://jsfiddle.net/L3ttfL72/

Comment: background-size:cover for the image, floats for the div, 50% width of wrapper.

Comment: I try to make a brief example jsdfidle to understand clearly, you edit the post immediately

Comment: I edited, can you show me more clearly now how do I do please?

Answer (score 0):

For square divs, give them the same height and width. For square divs the size of a percentage of the window width, use `vh`.

```css
div {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.container {
  width: 60vw
}
.banner {
  height: 17em; /* whatever you want */
  border-color:red; border-style:solid;
  border-width: 6px 6px 2px;
}
.bottom {
  float: left;
  width: 30vw;
  height: 30vw;
}
.left {
  border-color:green; border-style:solid;
  border-width:4px 3px 6px 6px;
}
.right {
  border-color:blue; border-style:solid;
  border-width:4px 6px 6px 3px;
}
.container::after {
  clear: left
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="banner">
    The top div
  </div>
  <div class="bottom left">
    bottom left
  </div>
  <div class="bottom right">
    bottom right
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code you requested. On a side note, I recommend [brushing](https://www.codecademy.com/) up on your html / css, this is a place to get assistance and posting questions similar is not recommended.

```
#numOne{
  width:60%;
  background:red;
  height:60vh;
}
#squareOne{
  background:green;
  width:50%;
  height:40vh;
  float:left;
}
#squareTwo{
  background:blue;
  width:50%;
  height:40vh;
  float:left;

}
#wrapperDiv{
  width:60%;
}
body{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
```

http://codepen.io/dnwebdev/pen/waRQme

```css
#numOne{
  width:60%;
  background:red;
  height:60vh;
 background-size:cover; background:url(http://lorempixel.com/output/cats-h-g-987-1010-10.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-position: center; 
}
#squareOne{
  background:green;
  width:50%;
  height:40vh;
  float:left;
 background-size:cover; background:url(http://lorempixel.com/output/cats-q-g-640-480-3.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-position: center; 
}
#squareTwo{
  background:blue;
  width:50%;
  height:40vh;
  float:left;
 background-size:cover; background:url(http://lorempixel.com/output/cats-q-g-640-480-3.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-position: center; 
  
}
#wrapperDiv{
  width:60%;
}
body{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">

  <div id="numOne">
  
  </div>
    <div id="wrapperDiv">
  <div id="squareOne">
  
  </div>
  <div id="squareTwo">
  
  </div>

</div>
</div>
```